# Loading specific files from arbitrary directories?

Tags: c++, boost, file-io

I want to load `foo.txt`.  `foo.txt` might exist in the `data/bar/` directory, or it might exist in the `data/New Folder/` directory.  There might be a different `foo.txt` in both of these directories, in which case I would want to either load one and ignore the other according to some order that I've sorted the directories by (perhaps manually, perhaps by date of creation), or else load them both and combine the results somehow.  The latter (combining the results of both/all `foo.txt` files) is circumstantial and beyond the scope of this question, but something I want to be able to do in the future.

I'm using SDL and `boost::filesystem`.  I want to keep my list of dependencies as small as possible, and as cross-platform as possible.

I'm guessing that my best bet would be to get a list of every directory (within the `data/` folder), sort/filter this list, then when I go to load `foo.txt`, I search for it in each potential directory?  This sounds like it would be very inefficient, if I have dozens of potential directories to search through every time.

What's the best way to go about accomplishing this?

Bonus:  What if I want some of the directories to be archives?  ie. considering both `data/foo/` and `data/bar.zip` to both be valid, and pull `foobar.txt` from either one without caring.

Comment: If you have a specific application data directory, the only thing that should vary between systems is the location of the data directory. Everything else inside it can and should be be at predefined paths from the data directory root. So no need to find anything, because you already know where it is.

Comment: Except I want my end-users to be able to install their own modules, to either replace the existing data files, or merge with them.  By dropping in a folder containing the new files, they can do so without having to touch any of the data that ships with the product.  I know exactly where the `data/` directory is, I don't know (or want to care) what directories are inside that.  Within *those* directories it becomes fixed paths again.

Comment: Most applications allowing such dynamic loading of modules or other configuration have specific sub-folders where the users have to put their files, or someway to tell the application where the files are. If you want a more loose hierarchy then you could have a fixed set of paths for the files that ship with your application, and a specific sub-folder where the users are allowed to use any hierarchy they want, and you could do recursive searches from that sub-folder.

Comment: That's pretty much the idea.  I have two `data/` folders, one in the app install directory where the shipped/packaged data goes, and one in the user directory where the loose/downloaded data goes.  Each "module" is a folder or archive within either of those two folders, and I don't want to care exactly where the data I need comes from.

Comment: Unfortunately there's really no "efficient" way of handling this searching, you simply have to go through the data directory [recursively](http://warpedvisions.org/blog/2008/04/howto-directory-recursion-in-boost-and-other-tips.md) to find the files you want. And more unfortunately there's no library in Boost to handle archive files, you have to add that support (with the added dependencies) yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  I ripped out `boost::filesystem`, and am now using [PhysicsFS](http://icculus.org/physfs/), which supports exactly what I need, is cross-platform, and uses `utf-8` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your method is really that "inefficient".  On my 1.6 GHz Atom D510 machine with Debian testing, searching for `stdio.h` over `/usr/include` (with some 1,300 dirs and 19,000 files) took only 2.2 and 0.7 seconds, without and with filesystem cache, respectively.

As for ZIP archive support, I don't think Boost can help you.  You need to rely on `libzip` or alternative libraries such as https://code.google.com/p/miniz/ (I haven't really tried this yet.)

Directory scan benchmark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost;

static void doFind(const filesystem::path &path) {
    if ( ! filesystem::exists(path)) {
        cout << "Non-existent [" << path << "]" << endl;
        return;
    }   

    if (is_directory(path)) {
        for (auto it = filesystem::directory_iterator(path), end = filesystem::directory_iterator(); it != end; ++it) {
            doFind(it->path());
        }   
    } else if (is_regular_file(path)) {
        if (path.filename() == "stdio.h")
            cout << "found [" << path << "]" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "cannot handle [" << path << "]" << endl;
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *root = "/usr/include";
    if (1 < argc)
        root = argv[1];

    auto t0 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    doFind(root);
    auto t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto msec = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    cout << "searching over [" << root << "] took " << msec.count() << " msec." << endl;
}
```

Software versions:

```
$ uname -a
Linux zbox 3.14-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.15-2 (2014-08-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.9.1-4) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ LANG=C dpkg -l libboost-filesystem-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-============================================================
ii  libboost-filesystem-dev:amd 1.55.0.2           amd64              filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over direct
```